# How to run mac OS command via JAVA?

Tags: java, macos

Hi guys :) I am new to JAVA and because I wanted to create something useful for myself I went on and tried to make an app that would put my computer to sleep after certain time.

Now I searched through internet how to run mac OS commands from java and got it partially working... I need to run this in order to put my computer to sleep:

```
sudo pmset schedule sleep "10/28/16 15:22:32"
```

and this is what I got:

```
String[] cmd = {"/usr/bin/pmset", "schedule", "sleep", "\""+time+" "+tajm+"\""};
```

where "time" gets me current date in the proper format and "tajm" gets me desired time. And when I run it I get this:

```
Error: Badly formatted date (2)
Error parsing scheduled event.
```

But if I run the code in terminal it works just fine even with the date...
also I tried this(just to test if sudo is needed):

```
String[] cmd2 = {"/usr/bin/sudo ", "/usr/bin/pmset ", "schedule ", "sleep ", "\""+time+" "+tajm+"\""};
```

but that gives me

```
Cannot run program "/usr/bin/sudo ": error=2, No such file or directory
```

I also edited sudoers so pmset doesn't require a password and I can successfully run

```
String[] cmd1 = {"/usr/bin/pmset", "sleepnow"};
```

but whenever I try to run the first code it just doesn't go through... I would appreciate any help. Thank you in advance

Comment: where is your actual code ?

Comment: Have you tried something like this? Runtime.getRuntime().exec("sudo pmset schedule sleep 10/28/16 15:22:32");

Comment: @ facundop yep.. that gives me `Cannot run program "sudo pmset schedule shutdown "10/28/16 16:52:20"": error=2, No such file or directory`